# UIButton in UITableViewCell subclass not registering taps

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a favorites button that I want to be able to tap in order to mark a cell as a favorite. The cell is also tappable.

This is a subclass UITableViewCell. I have added the button, but I am having trouble getting it to call the target action. In other words, I tap the button in the cell, but nothing happens:

```
class ServerSelectionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let isSelected = UIImage(named: "icon.png")
    let unselected = UIImage(named: "star.png")
    var favoriteButton: UIButton? = nil

    var server : Server? = nil {
        didSet{
            if let theServer = server {
                var server : String? = theServer.serverCode
                self.textLabel?.text = serverCode
                server?.isActive() { success in
                    self.accessoryType = success ? .Checkmark : .None
                }
            }
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        self.favoriteButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        self.favoriteButton?.setImage(unselected, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.favoriteButton?.setImage(isSelected, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        self.favoriteButton?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

        setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        self.favoriteButton?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.favoriteButton!)
    }

    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        println("Button tapped")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.favoriteButton?.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 35, 35)
        self.textLabel?.frame = CGRectMake(55, 5, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

The function buttonAction is never called. I've tried this both on simulator and on device, and I can see that when I tap on the favorite button, the cell is not selected, but the function is still not called.

Edit:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseId = "cell"
    tableView.registerClass(ServerSelectionTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseId) as ServerSelectionTableViewCell

    if let servers = getServers() {
        let server = servers[indexPath.row]

        cell.server = server
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if let servers = getServers() {
        let server = servers[indexPath!.row]
        var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as ServerSelectionTableViewCell

        println("Server selected \(server)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating the cell from an XIB or a Storyboard or allocated completely from class?

Comment: I am not using interface builder or storyboards for this, so I assume I am allocating completely from class

Comment: I dont see any problem in code you pasted, so I suppose problem is in some another part. Could you show, how you create UITableView and also cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: I don't know if this will make any difference, but you shouldn't set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false for the cell.

Comment: When you press the button does it select the table view cell?

Comment: I pasted my UITableView and cellForRowAtIndexPath. @keithbhunter When I press the button, it does NOT select the table view cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that the button WAS registering taps, but the line

`println("Button tapped")`

was not actually printing to the console, so I thought that it wasn't.